# YQL Request in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

I've been struggling to get this to work for a while. Basically I want to get information from Yahoo via the YQL resource. I have it working for all browsers except IE. (IE8 is the only one I've tested, but it's a must).

[A fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xHFHT/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fwebservice%2Fv1%2Fsymbols%2Fyhoo%2Fquote%3Fformat%3Djson%22%20and%20itemPath%20%3D%20%22list.resources.resource.fields%22&format=xml&callback=?',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        name = $($(data.results[0]).find('name')[0]).text();
        symbol = $($(data.results[0]).find('symbol')[0]).text();
        price = $($(data.results[0]).find('price')[0]).text();
        price = parseInt(price);
        $('body').append(name + '; ' + symbol + '; ' + price);
    }
});
```

The YQL request (for the console):

```
select * from json where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/yhoo/quote?format=json" and itemPath = "list.resources.resource.fields"
```

It's a simple Ajax get call, but I can't seem to get access for IE8 to do anything with the data. (The return dataType that you see in the URL doesn't matter-- I've tried it with both XML and JSON). Am I missing something? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are using `jQuery-2.0.2` but since `jQuery-2.0` it dropped the support for `IE-6/7/8`. From [jQuery 2.0 Released | Official jQuery Blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) :

> **No more support for IE 6/7/8:** Remember that this can also affect IE9
>   and even IE10 if they are used in their “Compatibility View” modes
>   that emulate older versions. To prevent these newer IE versions from
>   slipping back into prehistoric modes, we suggest you always use an
>   X-UA-Compatible tag or HTTP header. If you can use the HTTP header it
>   is slightly better for performance because it avoids a potential
>   browser parser restart.

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHFHT/1/) using `jQuery-1.9.1`.

Comment: Yup, I don't know why I didn't have that. I had it in my local test, but I think I was using the wrong YQL service.